# Rigging a complex character with clothes

Tags: rigging, armature

My workflow is as follows:

1. I created a low poly character. Each part of the body is a separate object. I also created joints.
2. Then I created underwear so that it could hide the joints and so that it was clothes at the same time. Here are socks, pants and a jacket.
3. Next, on top of the underwear, I created armor and armature.
   [image: modeling steps]
4. It's time to move the character. The fact is that thanks to the individual parts of the body, I can make them bones and the character moves perfectly.
5. I went to YouTube to find out how to solve the problem with clothes. However, I found only lessons where people create a character from one object, and the clothes that should move are just part of the form.
6. Then I found a lesson where they work with the weight of an object:

   A. Join the body of the character (<kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>J</kbd>) and set parent to the armature with automatic weights

   B. Joning all parts of the armor (<kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>J</kbd> and set parent to the armature with empty groups

   C. Select a character, then armor and go into weight mode

   D. Apply the settings.
7. Yes, the armor began to move with the body, but they literally became one object when moving. If I tilt my body stronger, the armor inside the body will be very ugly.

[image: armor rigging steps]

My question is: Can I make some (metal) armor really hard so that they do not deform when moving and hook them on a bone or joint?

Perhaps I created a problem by creating such a complex character, I'm new in the Blender.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to make something to deform like absolutely solid thing, you need to maintain the vertex weights of this part assigned to one single bone, and *only* this bone. That may lead to further problems though. Generally, skinning such "sandwich" chars as yours is always a pain in a butt, and you'll probably have to be ready to agree with some clipping in any case...

Comment: Thank u, Vedamir. It remains to understand how to transfer this to unity and create similar things for future sets)) What I did: for each element of armor I created a separate armature (inside the existing skeleton) and set parent to the armature as "bone". For each new reinforcement applied a bond to the corresponding human bone. That is, now, with the movement of the leg, the boot also moves. At what the boot has absolute strength and if I want, I can turn it.